# Building a vs2008 solution under vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm working on a solution that was developed under vs2008 but was opened and converted to vs2010. I was only given the vs2010 solution so I have to work under vs2010.

Is their a way to build this solution under vs2010 without using any of the vs2010 libs (Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\libs) and use only those used by vs2008

In Linker > General> Additionnal Library Directories, I've already added a link to the vs2008 libs folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the "General > Platform Toolset" property in the Visual Studio 2010 project properties to specify which version MSBuild should use to build your project. The default value is v100, but setting it to v90 would use Visual Studio 2008. This modifies your PATH, BIN, and LIB directories before compiling/linking, so you don't have to change any directory settings manually.

I think, by default only v100, v90, and Windows7.1SDK are supported, but there are tools available to target older Visual Studio versions as well.

See e.g. http://blog.iangoodsell.com/2010/04/visual-studio-2010-and-platform-toolset.html.